# why won't my logo appear for my wordpress theme?

Tags: image, wordpress, themes, loading, graphical-logo

I'm having trouble with my logo image loading when you first arrive at the index page.  It doesn't initially load.  However if you click one of the internal pages, it will then load fine after that. any ideas?

http://wilsoncain.com/
http://karinjillkatz.com/

I'm using the same theme on both sites.  The problem is the same on both.

Thanks for any suggestions, I have not been able to figure this out.

Comment: Hi Michael, this question would be better answerd over at [The Wordpress Stack Site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com) as SO is a `programming` community.

Comment: @MattClark, WordPress is also programming related and on `So` a lots of question and answers has been already submitted for `WordPress`, but sometimes it's better to for a wordPress related question to submit on `wordpress.stackexchange.com` to get better response.

Answer (score 0):

When you are loading your page, you do have a problem to load this picture : http://karinjillkatz.com/wp-content/themes/aries-orig/images/select_arrow.gif
You need to remove/correct the path so it won't break the rest of your website.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Google Chrome` (I am unsure if this feature exists in any of the other browsers as I do not use them), and right click anywhere on the page, you can click on `Inspect Element` which will sow you a bunch of details about the page.

In the inspector window, it will also tell you any errors that occured while loading the page... On your site (WilsonCain), `5` erros arose:

> 404: http://wilsoncain.com/wp-content/themes/aries/images/module_line.png
>   404: http://wilsoncain.com/wp-content/themes/aries/images/select_arrow.gif
>   404: http://wilsoncain.com/wp-content/themes/aries/Aaargh-webfont.woff
>   404: http://wilsoncain.com/wp-content/themes/aries/Aaargh-webfont.ttf
>   404: http://wilsoncain.com/wp-content/themes/aries/Aaargh-webfont.svg

And on your site (Karin Jill), `1` error arose:

> 404: http://karinjillkatz.com/wp-content/themes/aries-orig/images/select_arrow.gif

I would begin by looking into these images and correcting any paths to files that may no longer exist, or may have been renamed.